# Auto-completion & documentation of Python code

Tags: python

Can I use `index.d.ts` to enable custom code documentation & auto-completion for Python code as we do in JS? if so, how? If not, is there any equivalent for Python?

Comment: This PEP describes how you add annotations to Python code https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/

Comment: How about describing function params, what does this function do, return? seems the link describes only variables annotating

Comment: That's what docstrings are for https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there have been various additions to Python over time that allow you to do so.

As mentioned in the comments, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/ and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/ cover this in part.

See also the documentation on type hints here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Note that if you wanted to know how to provide type hints for a very specific example, you should have probably included some sample code that needed the hints, but hopefully the above helps.